# Render kml on google maps for android using any library

Tags: android, google-maps, kml

We students,  are currently working in firebase database, and the kml file is uploaded on storage. We found some demo projects about it, and it's using asynctask to fetch the file using the url(inputstream) but the url does not have any url parameters. On a firebase url there a certain parameters. On my opinion the problem is, The codes we found on a demo can't handle the firebase url and it's crashing, is there a way to fetch the file and render it to google maps?

here's are from the demo code

```
package com.google.maps.android.utils.demo;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.maps.android.data.Feature; 
import com.google.maps.android.data.kml.KmlContainer;
import com.google.maps.android.data.kml.KmlLayer;
import com.google.maps.android.data.kml.KmlPlacemark;
import com.google.maps.android.data.kml.KmlPolygon;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

public class KmlDemoActivity extends BaseDemoActivity {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private String TAG = "Result";

protected int getLayoutId() {
    return R.layout.kml_demo;
}

public void startDemo () {
    try {
        mMap = getMap();
        //retrieveFileFromResource();
        retrieveFileFromUrl();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Exception caught", e.toString());
    }
}

private void retrieveFileFromResource() {
    try {
        KmlLayer kmlLayer = new KmlLayer(mMap, R.raw.campus, getApplicationContext());
        kmlLayer.addLayerToMap();
        moveCameraToKml(kmlLayer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void retrieveFileFromUrl() {

    new DownloadKmlFile(getString(R.string.kml_url)).execute();
}

private void moveCameraToKml(KmlLayer kmlLayer) {
    //Retrieve the first container in the KML layer
    KmlContainer container = kmlLayer.getContainers().iterator().next();
    //Retrieve a nested container within the first container
    container = container.getContainers().iterator().next();
    //Retrieve the first placemark in the nested container
    KmlPlacemark placemark = container.getPlacemarks().iterator().next();
    //Retrieve a polygon object in a placemark
    KmlPolygon polygon = (KmlPolygon) placemark.getGeometry();
    //Create LatLngBounds of the outer coordinates of the polygon
    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    for (LatLng latLng : polygon.getOuterBoundaryCoordinates()) {
        builder.include(latLng);
    }

    int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    int height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
    getMap().moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builder.build(),     width, height, 1));
}

private class DownloadKmlFile extends AsyncTask<String, Void, byte[]> {
    private final String mUrl;

    public DownloadKmlFile(String url) {
        mUrl = url;
    }

    protected byte[] doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            InputStream is =  new URL(mUrl).openStream();
            ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int nRead;
            byte[] data = new byte[16384];
            while ((nRead = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);

            }
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: "+buffer);
            buffer.flush();
            return buffer.toByteArray();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(byte[] byteArr) {
        try {
            KmlLayer kmlLayer = new KmlLayer(mMap, new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArr),
                    getApplicationContext());
            kmlLayer.addLayerToMap();
            kmlLayer.setOnFeatureClickListener(new KmlLayer.OnFeatureClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFeatureClick(Feature feature) {
                    Toast.makeText(KmlDemoActivity.this,
                            "Feature clicked: " + feature.getId(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            moveCameraToKml(kmlLayer);
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

strings.xml contains the url

```
 <string name="kml_url">http://googlemaps.github.io/kml-samples/morekml/Polygons/Polygons.Google_Campus.kml</string>
```